# Getting rid of for loops in correlation matrix generation - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops

I am attempting to simulate a 2D field of non-stationary, single variable spatial data based on a correlation function in such a way that I can tweak various parameters and observe the effects.

Specifically, I am trying to (quickly) generate non-stationary data following a varying Matérn covariance structure based on equation (9) in this paper:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.3174.pdf

where R is Matérn or exponential covariance function, and Omega_s represents the covariance matrix at each point s.  After making an n^2 x n^2 cell of 2x2 Omega matrices `OMs`, which specify the way the simulated random field will correlate at given locations, I use the function below to build the correlation matrix:

```
rho = zeros(n^2);

for i = 1:n^2 % Point 1
    for j = 1:n^2 % Point 2

        if i == j
            rho(i,j) = 1;  % Correlation at lag 0 = 1

        else 
            x1 = Crd(i,1); y1 = Crd(i,2); % Crd is n^2 by 2 matrix of
            x2 = Crd(j,1); y2 = Crd(j,2); % coordinates in 2D

            % Lag vector
            h = [x1-x2;y1-y2];

            % Correlaton Function:
            R = exp(-norm(h)^alpha);
            Q = h'*(((OMs{x1,y1}+OMs{x2,y2})/2) \ h);
            OMEGA1 = (det(OMs{x1,y1})^(0.25))*det(OMs{x2,y2})^(0.25);
            OMEGA2 = det((OMs{x1,y1}+OMs{x2,y2})/2)^(-0.5);

            rho(i,j) = OMEGA1*OMEGA2*R*Q^(0.5);

        end
    end
end
```

Unfortunately, for moderately sized fields - even 40 by 40 - this takes a lot of time.  I need to run this for many different parameters - is there some way it can be done faster, without those loops?

Comment: You will achieve enormous speed up by replacing your second line with `for j = i+1:n^2`. Since `rho(i,j) = rho(j,i)` don't calculate them all as you effectively calculate each of them twice. The rest looks OK, you could further speed up by running the first loop in parallel.

Comment: Thank you @PetrH; good eye and good call on the symmetry.  That speeds things up in a big way.

As for running in parallel, it does not seem to like the way I have rho laid out (cannot be classified).  Is that because it is dependent on other functions within the loop?

Comment: It has been a long time since I read how the parallelization works in MATLAB. What you want is to run the first loop in parallel and have `rho`, `Crd` and `OMs` public, the rest are private variables. I don't remember if MATLAB actually allows you to specify this or it guesses itself, in which case it might guess incorrectly. Perhaps what might be confusing MATLAB is that `rho` is within the `if`, `else` construct but that you should remove anyway (place `rho(i,i)=1` before the second loop).